# How to set tty-clock output as background

Tags: background, tty, i3

I would like to set **tty-clock** output as background for my i3 setup.
I want to know how to display a command output as background.

Things I tried so far:

1. Running a script that supposedly would run tty-clock and take its screenshot with **scrot** once a minute and **feh** would set it as background.

   Problem: tty-clock would stay on without ever letting next command to run and scrot is a screenshot utility and it would capture whatever I am looking at. Or I would need to switch to that workspace every minute to run, shot, kill, set as background.

```
tty-clock && killall tty-clock
scrot ~/Pictures/Wallpaper/background.png
feh ~/Pictures/Wallpaper/background.png
```

2. save tty-clock output to a file which supposedly would be converted into image by **convert** (by imagemagick) and **feh** would set it as background.

   Problem: tty-clock output is more than just clock which I guess give information about characters' colors or place.

```
tty-clock | cat > ~/TEMP/tty-clock-output
```

tty-clock-output

```
[?1049h[22;0;0t[1;39r(B[m[4l[?7h[?1h=[39;49m[?25l[39;49m(B[m[H[2J[17;59H[H[2J[7;12H[17;59H
[64G[45m  
[Z  
[Z  
[Z  
[Z  [49m(B[m[18d [45m  [49m(B[m  [45m  
[67G  [49m(B[m  [45m  
[67G      
  
  [49m(B[m[18;79H[45m      [19;75H  [49m(B[m  [45m  [49m(B[m  [45m  
[79G  [49m(B[m  [45m  [21;75H  [49m(B[m  [45m  [49m(B[m  [45m  
[79G      [49m(B[m[18d [45m  [49m(B[m  [45m  
[86G  [49m(B[m  [45m  
[86G      
  
  [49m(B[m[22;66H [22;85H[92G[22;66H   [22;85H[92G[22;66H   [22;85H[92G[22;66H   [22;85H[92G[22;66H   [22;85H[92G[22;66H   [22;85H[92G[22;66H   [22;85H[92G[39;1H[?12l[?25h[?1049l[23;0;0t
[?1l>[?1049h[22;0;0t[1;39r(B[m[4l[?7h[?1h=[39;49m[?25l[39;49m(B[m[H[2J[17;59H[H[2J[7;12H[17;59H
[64G[45m  
[Z  
[Z  
[Z  
[Z  [49m(B[m[18d [45m  [49m(B[m  [45m  
[67G  [49m(B[m  [45m  
[67G      
  
  [49m(B[m[18;79H[45m      [19;75H  [49m(B[m  [45m  [49m(B[m  [45m  
[79G  [49m(B[m  [45m  [21;75H  [49m(B[m  [45m  [49m(B[m  [45m  
[79G      [49m(B[m[18d [45m      
[86G  
      
  
[86G      [49m(B[m[22;66H  [22;85H[92G[22;66H   [22;85H[92G[39;1H[?12l[?25h[?1049l[23;0;0t
[?1l>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to invoke tty-clock at all: a script which sends the output of `date` (formatted to suit) to a text file, and then runs `convert` on that should do the trick. You'll need to spend some time playing with the `convert` parameters to get the desired look of course.

Comment: Expected & achieved results are [here](https://imgur.com/a/OL5f0Kx)
i really wanted to have blocky tty-clock font but it was not available in figlet fontDB.
I will update my question if I get the solution I wanted.

Comment: Any particular reason you're using figlet? You can use any installed font with convert.

Comment: I know I can enlarge any font as much as I want (I learned that yesterday :) but I really like the tty-clock style and I don't know any monospace font with same style. I even looked at [tty-clock source code](https://github.com/xorg62/tty-clock) to find the font tty-clock uses but it uses [drawnumber function](https://github.com/xorg62/tty-clock/blob/0cec6b099385d0db33fe81ae3d0d34e15ed40430/ttyclock.c#L221) instead.

Comment: Incorporating that in your own code would seem to be the answer then!